# Программа, ищущая в папках название файла как папка, появилась сложность.. HELP?

Tags: delphi

MyRemove как использовать?

Что нужно прописать в начале кода, где uses?
И ешё со sDir проблемка...

Comment: А почему антивирус нельзя использовать? И, как мне кажется, лучше сначала искать место, где сам вирус сидит. Ведь, если его экзешники из всех папок удалить, а его самого не грохнуть, то толку мало будет.

Comment: Потому-что на предприятии нельзя использовать палёные программы без лицензии, так есть исходники по этому делу ?

Comment: Попробуйте утилитой AVZ просканировать или каким-нибудь другим бесплатным сканером. У меня исходников нет - подобные вещи не делал.

Comment: Дочего народ хитрый пошел :)

Всякие ухищрения начал придумывать что бы ему помогли лабу сделать...

Код дай, коментарии допишите... совесть бы поимел :)

Comment: Извени просто некоторые процедуры мне не совсем известны ... 

Не хочешь не надо сам потихоньку разберусь

Comment: Методом тыка!!!

Comment: С декларациями проблемка

Answer (score 1):

```
 procedure TForm1.MyRemove(sdir: string);
 var
  iIndex: integer; // индекс найденного файла
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  sFileName: string;
  dir: string;
 begin
  sDir:= sDir + '\*.*'; // устанавливаем поиск любого 
                        // файла внутри указанной директории
  iIndex:= FindFirst(sDir, faAnyFile, SearchRec); // находим первый файл в директории

  while iIndex = 0 do
   begin
    sFileName:= ExtractFileDir(sDir) + '\' + SearchRec.Name; // выбираем найденный  
                                                             // файл

    if SearchRec.Attr = faDirectory then   // если это директория
     begin                                 // смотрим её название
       if (SearchRec.Name <> '') and       // пропускаем эти названия  
       (SearchRec.Name <> '.') and
       (SearchRec.Name <> '..') then
         MyRemove(sFileName);              // открываем это директорию для 
                                           // прочесывания
     end
    else  // если это не папка
     begin
       if SearchRec.Attr <> faArchive then
         FileSetAttr(sFileName, faArchive);

       if Pos('.exe', SearchRec.Name) <> 0 then   // смотрим название файла
         begin                                    // если это ехешник
           dir:= sDir;                                  //находим название папки
           Delete(dir, Pos('\*.*', dir), Length(dir));  // --//--
           while Pos('\', Dir) <> 0 do                  // --//--
             Delete(dir, 1, Pos('\', dir));             // --//--
           // Если название ехешника = названию папки в которой он лежит
           if dir = Copy(SearchRec.Name, 1, Pos('.exe', SearchRec.Name) - 1) then
             // то удаляем ехешник
             DeleteFile(sFileName)
         end;
     end;
    // смотрим следующиу файл
    iIndex:= FindNext(SearchRec);
   end;
   // заканчиваем прочесывание
   FindClose(SearchRec);
 end;
```

Comment: передаешь в процедуру директорию, в которой искать. после чего процедура будет просматривать все папки в данной директории и искать файл.ехе, у которого имя будет = названию папки в которой лежит файл

Comment: Молочина надо испробывать!!!! А можешь немного код прокоментировать, а то мне не всё понятно iIndex:= FindNext(SearchRec)это что когода пииск закончился ?

Comment: добавил комменты

Comment: uses надо что нибудь добовлять ?

Comment: У меня с   идентификаторрами проблемы [Error] Unit1.pas (7): Декларация ожидалось, но "sDir" идентификатор найден
[Error] Unit1.pas (25): необъявленный идентификатор: 'MyRemove "
[Error] Unit1.pas (32): необъявленный идентификатор: 'sDir "
[Error] Unit1.pas (46): необъявленный идентификатор: 'MyRemove "
[Внимание] Unit1.pas (51):"faArchive" Символ специфичен для платформы
[Внимание]Unit1.pas (52):"FileSetAttr"Символ специфичен для платформы
[Внимание]Unit1.pas(52):"faArchive"Символ специфичен для платформы
[Error]Unit1.pas(11):Неудовлетворенные вперед или внешнее объявление:"TForm1.FormCreate

Comment: Даже если индентификаторы обьявлены появляються другие грабли type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyRemove(Sender: TObject);
    procedure sDir(Sender: TObject);

Comment: [Error] Unit1.pas(27): Declaration of 'MyRemove' differs from previous declaration
[Error] Unit1.pas(34): Undeclared identifier: 'sDir'
[Error] Unit1.pas(48): Undeclared identifier: 'MyRemove'
[Warning]Unit1.pas(53): Symbol 'faArchive' is specific to a platform
[Warning]Unit1.pas(54): Symbol 'FileSetAttr' is specific to a platform
[Warning]Unit1.pas(54): Symbol 'faArchive' is specific to a platform
[Error]Unit1.pas(11): Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TForm1.FormCreate'
[Error]Unit1.pas(13): Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TForm1.sDir'